# puppeteer fails in angular with ionic Can't resolve './types/other'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, puppeteer

I get the following error on angular 7 and ionic 4

```
./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/mime/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './types/other' in 'myapp\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\mime'
```

already install

"@types/puppeteer": "^1.12.2",

this is my file home.page.ts
I already tried this and it does not work https://www.lewuathe.com/using-puppeteer-in-typescript.html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

    onSubmitBuscar(){

        try {
        (async () => {
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.goto('https://example.com');
          await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

          await browser.close();
        })();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not launch puppeteer from angular!
Because of angular run on chrome and u can not access from chrome to os for open new chrome apliction u have to run puppeteer from nodejs